# kill application after crash

Tags: android, crash, kill

I haven't manage  all errors on my application anymore. So I would like to know if it is possible to Kill the entire app when it crashes?

(when the message "app MyApp crash, force close" appear, I would like the application to be killed when user clicks on "force close")

Answer (score 8):

This is actually what happens. If your app crashes with a force close, the entire application is killed. So, there is nothing more to "kill". All memory occupied by the application (packagename) is freed.

Comment: In fact, sometimes this doesn't work. When I clic on "force close" the message come out again and again. And the application was never killed

Comment: And just after that the previous activity is automatically restarted in most cases. This may look like your app is continuing to run.

If you would kill your app manually the system will recognize a strange stop of your app and restart it. So killing your app should not have any effect.

Comment: Ok, so I couldn't do what I want. Actually I use "task killer" to kill my app, I thought that I could do the same in my app

(Note : Sorry for grammatical errors, it isn't an excuse but I am French )

Comment: You can kill your app like you would with a task killer, but if you have to do that it means your code is wrong